# Prove Exponential series from Binomial Expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, exponential-function

I try to prove the Exponential series :

$$\exp(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{k!}$$

From the definition of the exponential function $$\exp(x) \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

I've tried a Binomial expansion of $\exp(x)$ like :
$$\begin{split}
\exp(x) &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\dfrac{x^k}{n^k}\\
&= 1 + \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{x^k}{k!}\times \dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!\times n^k}\right)\\
&= 1 + \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}\prod_{j=1}^{k}\left(\dfrac{n-(j-1)}{n}\right)\\
&= 1 + \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}\prod_{j=1}^{k}\left(1-\dfrac{j-1}{n}\right)\\
\end{split}$$

Here is my problem. If I apply the limit, obtain :
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{j-1}{n} = (j-1) \times \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n} = 0$$

But $j$ approaches $k$ which approaches $n$, so $j$ approaches the infinity... and the limit is indeterminate : $\infty \times 0 = \,?$

How to evaluate this indeterminate form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For proving that a function is equal to its Taylor series, don't we show that the Error Term $R(x:a)$ approaches $0$ as $x$ tends to infinity.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_characterizations_1_and_2

Comment: Is possible to make an induction hypothesis for each $j$ about the limit (to extend the limit from $j=1$ to $j+1$ rank) ? @Marco Cantarini thanks but how to prove the liminf/limsup inequality if $e^x$ definition is supposed "non-convergent yet" ?

Comment: @SuperFoxy Sorry but I don't understand what's the problem. You have to start to read from " Now, for the other direction...". In that case the hypothesis is $e^{x}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}$.

Comment: Ok I understood ^^

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it like this:
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}1^{n-k}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^{k}}&\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{n!}{k!\;(n-k)!}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^{k}}&\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{(n-k)!\;(n-(k-1))\ldots n}{k!\;(n-k)!}1^{n-k}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^{k}}&\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{(n-(k-1))\ldots n}{k!}\frac{x^{k}}{n^{k}}}&\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\frac{n-(k-1)}{n}\ldots\frac{n}{n}}&\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\ldots}&
\end{align}
Then apply the limit:
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\ldots}}&\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{k}}{k!}}&
\end{align}
Ta-dah. Hope this helps.